# jquery.dataTables.min.js:50 Uncaught TypeError: h(...).val(...).on is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, datatables-1.10

This HTML page I am rendering goes on the bottom of a pricelist page. When I try to call DataTable on the table, i get the following error.. which is very strange. Can't seem to figure out why its throwing this error.

```
jquery.dataTables.min.js:50 Uncaught TypeError: h(...).val(...).on is not a function
at nb (VM6942 jquery.dataTables.min.js:50)
at mb (VM6942 jquery.dataTables.min.js:32)
at ga (VM6942 jquery.dataTables.min.js:48)
at e (VM6942 jquery.dataTables.min.js:92)
at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (VM6942 jquery.dataTables.min.js:92)
at Function.each (jquery-latest.js:45)
at init.each (jquery-latest.js:38)
at init.m [as dataTable] (VM6942 jquery.dataTables.min.js:82)
at init.h.fn.DataTable (VM6942 jquery.dataTables.min.js:164)
```

My html file:

```
<html>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial;
        }

        table {
            font-size: 12px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 2px solid black;
        }

        #tableHead {
            background-color: lightgrey
        }
    </style>

    <body style="justify-content: justify">
        <div id="tableContainer">
            <div style="justify-content: center; float:left">
                <table id="partsTable" class="tablesorter">
                    <thead id="tableHead">
                        <th>Price List Name</th>
                        <th>Part Number</th>
                        <th>SPA</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Quantity Type</th>
                        <th>Customer Part Number</th>
                        <th>Design Registration</th>
                        <th>Lead Time</th>
                        <th>Quoted Cost</th>
                        <th>Quoted User Price</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tableBody"></tbody>
                </table>
                <div id="pager" class="pager">
                    <form>
                        <img src="../_imgs/first.png" class="first" />
                        <img src="../_imgs/prev.png" class="prev" />
                        <input type="text" class="pagedisplay" />
                        <img src="../_imgs/next.png" class="next" />
                        <img src="../_imgs/last.png" class="last" />
                        <select class="pagesize">
                            <option value="">>LIMIT</option>
                            <option value="2">2 per page</option>
                            <option value="5">5 per page</option>
                            <option value="10">10 per page</option>
                        </select>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var pricelistId = getParameterByName("id");
        var orgname = getParameterByName("orgname");
        getPriceListItems(pricelistId, orgname);
        var table = document.getElementById("partsTable");
        table.border = "5";
        table.style = "width: 100%; table-layout: flex;";

        $("#partsTable").DataTable();

        function getPriceListItems(id, orgname) {
            trakPlatformClient.RequestHandler.Execute({
                request: {
                    orgName: orgname,
                    messageName: "sp_get_dwpricelistitem",
                    parameters: [{
                        Key: "pt_designwinpricelistid",
                        Value: id
                    }]
                },
                context: this,
                responseHandler: getItemSuccess,
                handlerArgument: null,
                errorHandler: getItemError
            });
        }

        function getParameterByName(name, url) {
            if (!url) url = window.location.href;
            name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
            var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
                results = regex.exec(url);
            if (!results) return null;
            if (!results[2]) return '';
            return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }

        function getItemSuccess(result, handlerArgument) {
            var parts = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < result.Table.Rows.length; i++) {
                parts.push(result.Table.Rows[i]);
            }
            console.log(parts);
            var tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody");
            for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                var pt_designwinpricelistidname = parts[i].pt_designwinpricelistidname;
                var pt_designwinpricelistitemid = parts[i].pt_designwinpricelistitemid;
                var row = tableBody.insertRow(-1);
                var hiddenCell = row.insertCell(-1);
                hiddenCell.id = "pricelistID" + i;
                hiddenCell.value = pt_designwinpricelistitemid;
                hiddenCell.innerHTML = pt_designwinpricelistidname;
                hiddenCell.style.visibility = "visible";
                var pt_partidname = parts[i].pt_partidname;
                var am_spaname = parts[i].am_spaname;
                var am_quantitytype = parts[i].am_quantitytype;
                var quantity = parts[i].quantity;
                var am_customerpartnumber = parts[i].am_customerpartnumber;
                var pt_designregistrationpartidname = parts[i].pt_designregistrationpartidname;
                var am_leadtime = parts[i].am_leadtime;
                var am_quotedcost = parts[i].am_quotedcost.toPrecision(5);
                var am_quoateduserprice;
                if (parts[i].am_quoteduserprice != null) {
                    am_quoateduserprice = parts[i].am_quoteduserprice.toPrecision(5);
                } else {
                    var num = 0
                    am_quoateduserprice = num.toPrecision(5);
                }
                var statuscode = parts[i].statuscode;
                var statuscodename;
                if (statuscode == 1) {
                    statuscodename = "Active";
                } else {
                    statuscodename = "Inactive";
                }
                var quantitytypename;
                if (am_quantitytype == 1) {
                    quantitytypename = "Annual"
                } else if (am_quantitytype == 2) {
                    quantitytypename = "Quarterly"
                } else {
                    quantitytypename = "One Shot"
                }
                var attributes = new Array();
                attributes.push(pt_partidname);
                attributes.push(am_spaname);
                attributes.push(quantity);
                attributes.push(quantitytypename);
                attributes.push(am_customerpartnumber);
                attributes.push(pt_designregistrationpartidname);
                attributes.push(am_leadtime);
                attributes.push(am_quotedcost);
                attributes.push(am_quoateduserprice);
                attributes.push(statuscodename);
                for (var j = 0; j < attributes.length; j++) {
                    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                    cell.innerHTML = attributes[j];
                    if (j == 0) {
                        cell.style = "text-decoration: underline";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function getItemError(e, s, t) {
            console.log(e);
        }


    });
```

I'm not sure why DataTables won't initialize my table. It has thead and tbody, and I am lost as to the error returned.

Comment: You're using an old version of Jquery